# Import Job to Jenkins from xml

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am new in jenkins and docker.I am trying to import jenkins new job from xml file.Current jenkins is running inside docker.(jenkinsci/blueocean).

Here is my command:

```
java -jar .\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ create-job jobname .\myjob.xml
```

Here is error:

> anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission

What I have done:

I already check this one

[Anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/fixing-jenkins-cli-error-anonymous-missing-overallread-permission)

So I test with this cmd:

```
java -jar .\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ -auth username:password who-am-i
```

It return

```
 Authenticated as : username 
 Authorities: authenticated
```

Then I also try like that :

```
java -jar .\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 create-job jobname .\myjob.xml -auth username:password
```

its also happen error.

Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will prefer job import at build time, Here is the working example that you can try.

```
FROM jenkinsci/blueocean 
COPY config.xml /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jobs/job_name/config.xml
```

You can try working below command to run demo job import

```
git clone https://github.com/Adiii717/docker-jenkins-job-import.git
cd docker-jenkins-job-import;
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

Comment: honestly, where should i run this cmd?

Comment: this is when you build docker image `docker build -t myjenkinsimage .`

Comment: or the other option is install with https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-import-plugin/ job import plugin.

Comment: why i cant find this job-import-plugin in plugin manager of jenkins?

Comment: are you looking into available plugin?

Comment: I think I miss something. first i tried to run this docker build -t myimagename. but it say "docker  build" requires exactly 1 argement.

Comment: `docker build -t myimagename .` need `dot` at need for context.

Comment: I tried this cmd. but "unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path:CreateFile C:\.... The System cannot find the file specified"

Comment: I also dont see the file .

Comment: Now i tried to copy my config.xml to docker by using this cmd (docker cp "Configure Jenkins"xml yourcontainername:/var/jenkins_home).

Comment: Now jenkins cant run on local host.

Comment: I update answer and add link to demo project please check.

Comment: oh my bad. updated `git clone https://github.com/Adiii717/docker-jenkins-job-import.git`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216922/discussion-between-loran-and-adiii).